# How to call the same fragment with another value of argument assigned?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I am working on a development of an app, and currently dealing with the following: 
- I have a fragment using certain view comprised of buttons and `TextFields` (say showing user's detail information). Now, I have to call the same fragment (within this fragment) on another instance of data (e.g. say the details of another user, once certain button is clicked), but hiding some parts of the view when the new data are shown (i.e. the data for the new user, when the button is clicked). Considering that, I was wondering what approach should I use for calling the same fragment again, and having partially the same view as before. Could anyone of let me know what would be a good approach to go for?

Comment: You can use FragmentTransaction add() method for this kind of operation.

go through https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction

Comment: @HardikVegad thanks for your reply. Yes, that's right. But, I have also to put some additional parameter showing that this this is inside the user's detail view, and thus later being able to hide some parts of the view if this instance of fragment is called inside the view. Do you have any suggestion for that?

Comment: You can sure, you might use newInstance() method of the same fragment to put additional parameter, You can pass some flag and handle the operation, Rather I don;t have any idea how did you code that I am not sure yet.